# Не видит в проекте отдельные формы

Tags: c++-cli

Включил в Главный проект новые формы(Проект-добавить новый элемент-UI-форма Windows Forms) и создал 2 дополнительные формы.

Затем мне нужно переходить с главной формы на 2-ую и обратно(одним словом между 3-мя формами должна быть связь)

Для начала я добавил их в главную форму.В его `include` перед `namespace`-ом

```
    #pragma once

    #include "About.h"
    #include "PuasEqu.h"
    #include "NavieStoks.h"

    namespace TransEqu 
{
///методы,код и всё остальное
}
```

После уже прописываю через события

```
private: System::Void уравнениеПуассонаToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        PuasEqu^ PsE = gcnew PuasEqu();
        PsE->Show();
    }


private: System::VoidуравнениеНавьеСтоксаToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    NavieStoks^ NvStk = gcnew NavieStoks();
    NvStk->Show();
}
```

Но при компиляции в этих 4-рёх строчках находится куча ошибок таких как
- `2061(error C2061: синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "NavieStoks")` -
- `2065(error C2065: PsE: необъявленный идентификатор)`

2)Посмотрел в свои созданные формы и там аналогичная проблема.

```
#pragma once

#include "About.h"
#include "PuasEqu.h"
#include "TransEquForm.h"

namespace TransEqu {
```

всё аналогично сделал(и следовательно аналогичные ошибки)

```
private: System::Void модельУравненияПереносаToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        TransEquForm^ Trnseqfrm = gcnew TransEquForm();
        Trnseqfrm->Show();
    }

    private: System::Void уравнениеПуассонаToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        PuasEqu^ PsE = gcnew PuasEqu();
        PsE->Show();
    }
```

Проблема в том,что компилятор просто их не видит,и пишет что неизвестный идентификатор и следом идёт синтаксическая ошибка.

И хочу узнать почему так и как это можно решить?
Ведь в коде всё видно,в автозаполнении есть все классы.
А вот компилятор думает иначе.

UPDATE!!!!

UPD

Перенёс всё в отдельный файл .cpp объявил там namespace проекта своего

```
private: System::Void TransEquationToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    TransEquForm^ TrnEqFr = gcnew TransEquForm();
    TrnEqFr->Show();
}
    private: System::Void PuasonEquationToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        PuasEqu^ PsE = gcnew PuasEqu();
        PsE->Show();
    }
```

НО возникает уже другая проблема, ведь методы отвечающие за нажатие мышкой перенесены в отдельный файл и следовательно компилятор начинает выдавать ошибки.

Вот к примеру в конструкторе формы

```
// TransferEquationToolStripMenuItem// 
this->TransferEquationToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"TransferEquationToolStripMenuItem";
this->TransferEquationToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(212, 22);
this->TransferEquationToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"TransferEquation";
this->TransferEquationToolStripMenuItem->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &PuasEqu::TransferEquationToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
// NavieStoksEquationToolStripMenuItem
            // 
this->NavieStoksEquationToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"NavieStoksEquationToolStripMenuItem";
this->NavieStoksEquationToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(212, 22);
this->NavieStoksEquationToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"NavieStoksEquation";
this->NavieStoksEquationToolStripMenuItem->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &PuasEqu::NavieStoksEquationToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            //
```

В любой из 3-ёх форм находятся куча ошибок

Вот к примеру только в одной этой строке

```
this->TransferEquationToolStripMenuItem->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &NavieStoks::TransferEquationToolStripMenuItem_Click);
```

И вот такие ошибки

```
error C3924: Error in delegate delegate argument # 2 "System::EventHandler":    
error C2039: TransEquationToolStripMenuItem_Click: не является членом "TransEqu::NavieStoks"
```

Comment: Вероятно, вы столкнулись с проблемой перекрёстных ссылок. Чтобы избежать её, весь код ваших форм должен быть в файлах .cpp, а в файлах .h - только объявления, в том числе инклюды. Кстати, переходите на C# - в нём нет этой проблемы ;).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov перейти на С# не получится,нужно именно на C++
А теперь вопрос по перекрёстным ссылкам

В файл .cpp что нужно именно кидать?Ведь код вызова из menustrip в cpp файл просто так не закинешь,так как компилятор заругается на объявления,но оказывается, что объявления нужно в .h файлах оставлять.